# How to set user account to auto-login in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: 16.04

what are the commands for setting user account to auto-login at boot? please help. I set my full disk during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings (in the drop down menu at the top right corner), then choose 'User accounts', select the user. Then click on 'unlock', enter your password and set the switch 'Automatic Login' to on.